# Is there a way to retrieve the collection of all view paths?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to get the view files that have rendered on the current page request. There's an item in `HttpContext.Current.Items` that contains a collection of paths, but that object does not appear exist in the Items collection when running the code on an actual server (as opposed to a dev box). Is there a way to retrieve the collection of all view paths?

Comment: I'm curious, Why do you need it?

Comment: Working with a system upgraded from MVC2 that had this weird inheritable plugin system where it would only render the plugged-in view (into the Master page content) if the current requested page matched a specific segment of the plugin view name. Works fine in WebForms view engine because of how it does inheritance, but Razor doesn't actually inherit layouts/pages the same way and the site is getting converted to Razor.

Comment: `ViewContext.View.ViewPath` and `ViewContext.View.LayoutPath` will get you part of it, not sure how you can get the entire collection easily with Razor without overriding the view engine or view, you could just write to the context collection manually at the top of each view